# PhoneGap Build - Set splash-screen for Android devices

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, phonegap-build

I'm currently trying to set an splash-screen for Android devices in PhoneGap build. I set 4 different screens, but somehow the screens get deformed and lost their aspect ratio. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: did you replace original splash screens with images of the same size?

Comment: What do you mean by _screens get deformed_? If you're talking about very ugly streched splash screen on Android device in landscape orientation, then this is a confirmed bug ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14883769/1469208)). PhoneGap Build (and problably PhoneGap itself as well) currently does not support landscape splash screens at all. I even tired the iOS way, like `Red2678` shown below, but it still doesen't work. All is fine in portrait mode, but no matter, what screen density Android device you'll use -- in landscape you'll see ugly deformed portrait version of splash screen.

Comment: Hello, did u use a .9.png formate? It get's deformed in portrait mode, but i only used .png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do'h, missing that the question was about Android, here is the Android section from my config.xml:

```
<gap:splash src="img/splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="img/splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="img/splash/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<!--<gap:splash src="splash/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />-->
```

Yes, Apple is much easier! On Android they go by qualifier called "densities".

To my knowledge PhoneGap Build only supports three of the four right now. ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and NOT xdpi (that is why it is commented out above).

All Android devices will use one of these four sizes, is my understanding. Obtaining perfect aspect ratio across hundreds of different devices may be a little challenging, but with this you at least get close .

Read this, I know it is a lot, but worth the reading:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

And, the PGB Guidelines: http://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Answer (score 1):

we can set this in three ways

1. through config.xml
2. through the activity class setting the property
3. through script

to refer more sample source code sample source code with example for phonegap-build-set-splash-screen

http://getmebyclickme.blogspot.in/2013/10/phonegap-build-set-splash-screen-for.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
   import org.apache.cordova.*;

  public class RemindMeActivity extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);


}
}
```

this will help u to show splash screen using phonegap

Comment: Hi, thanks. As i'm using phonegap build it isn't possible to change something in the java project, as i'm just deploying the www files and a config file where i can add the screenies. Is it even possible with phonegap build?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have them my PGB config.xml (your folder structure and file names will vary), this supports most IOS devices I believe. How many launch images do you have?

```
<gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/Default.png" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/Default_at_2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/Default_iphone5.png" width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/Default-Landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/Default-Portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/Hi-Rez-Portrait.png" width="1536" height="2008" />
<gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/Hi-Rez-Landscape.png" width="2048" height="1496" />
```

Apple's guidlines:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Phonegap Build's guidelines:http://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Comment: Hello, thank's but the question was about the Android stuff :) The iOS Screenies are a lot easier to arrange. But thank's anyway.