# Landscape splash screen for Android in PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova, landscape, phonegap-build, splash-screen

What should I enter to `config.xml` or what should I do in general, to have PhoneGap Build application's splash screen displayed correctly on Android device in landscape mode?

PhoneGap Build (used to compile) [docs](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml#splashes) / [blog](https://build.phonegap.com/blog/enhanced-icon-and-splash-support) have nothing on this. Only Portrait is covered for Android.

Since first (docs) says that using `height` and `width` is cross-platform supported, I tried to use it:

```
<gap:splash src="res/splash-200x320-android.png"             gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi"  width="200" height="320" />
<gap:splash src="res/splash-320x480-android-bada-ios.png"    gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"  width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/splash-480x800-android-bada-wp.png"     gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"  width="480" height="800" />
<gap:splash src="res/splash-720x1280-android.png"            gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" width="720" height="1280" />
<gap:splash src="res/splash-320x200-android.png"             gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi"  width="320" height="200" />
<gap:splash src="res/splash-480x320-android-bada-ios.png"    gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"  width="480" height="320" />
<gap:splash src="res/splash-800x480-android-bada-wp.png"     gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"  width="800" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/splash-1280x720-android.png"            gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" width="1280" height="720" />
```

But there is no effect -- in landscape mode on my Android device I always see badly strechead portait  mode version of my splash screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per my current knowledge and after deep research, I have found that this is a confirmed bug, and we currently can't do anything about this.

PhoneGap Build (and probably PhoneGap itself as well) currently does not support landscape splash screens at all. I even tried the iOS way (like shown in the question -- using `width` and `height` params, officially not supported for Android). But it still doesn't work.

All is fine in portrait mode, but no matter what screen density Android device you'll use -- in landscape you'll see ugly deformed portrait version of splash screen.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not using PhoneGap Build, but I managed to fix this in a basic PhoneGap Android app.

Let's say you have two different splash images - a landscape and a portrait version - and you want both of them to stretch to fill the available screen area.

Put one in `drawable` and the other in `drawable-land`.  (Or `drawable-land-hdpi`, `drawable-land-xhdpi`, etc., if you you have multiple sizes.)

Next, make sure that you're managing config changes yourself in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<activity
    ...
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
    ...
>
</activity>
```

Then put this in your main Activity class that extends `DroidGap.java`:

```java
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (super.splashDialog != null) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) super.splashDialog.getWindow()
                .getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.getChildAt(0);
        // manually refresh the splash image
        linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mysplash);
    }
}
```

This will cause the background image to redraw and properly stretch whenever the user changes orientation.

Comment: This is nice looking solution (so +1), but I'm not going to accept it as it is way too off-topic. The idea of my question was to bring answer specific to PhoneGap Build -- that is, using HTML/Javascript and `config.xml` only. You don't have abillity to use pure Java code in PhoneGap Build apps, don't you?

Comment: @LarryAasen No, you can't! Read my comment. I'm talking about _PhoneGap **Build**_. When using [PGB](https://build.phonegap.com/) (building in the cloud) you're limited to HTML/Javascript only. You can use pure Java code only, if you're building locally, in your own environment.

Comment: @trejder you need to rephrase your question to include build if that is the case. Otherwise, my comment is correct.

Comment: @LarryAasen I used: _PhoneGap Build (used to compile)_ part in my question and author of answer, you're commenting (_nlawson_) started his answer with: _I'm not using PhoneGap Build, but..._. Seems most people understand, that this question is about PhoneGap Build only. But, if this will make you happy, I see no problem in changing question's title! :]

Answer (score 3):

Phonegap Build now uses the [Cordova configuration style](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#example-configuration). When specifying the `density`, append `port-` or `land-` to specify portrait or landscape:

```
<splash src="portrait-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
<splash src="landscape-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
```

---

*Old configuration style*

It can be done since April 2014 in Phonegap Build by using the `gap:qualifer`, eg

```
<gap:splash src="portrait-xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xxhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="landscape-xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-xxhdpi" />
```

See [this](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/11/phonegap-build-adds-some-new-features/) and [this](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html) article for details.